# NodeJS https server returning ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https

I'm trying to get SSL https working on my nodejs server but the browser returns a ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

code:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
}

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Comment: That should work `https.createServer(sslOptions, app)`, verify you are getting the certificates correctly. When reading the files maybe you need to add **__dirname + 'key.pem'**

Answer (score 6):

This will happen if your key isn't generated correctly.

A lot of places will tell you to do this:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
```

That will not work if you're on a Mac, and instead you need to do this to make the key length 2048:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
```

In summary, do these steps to make a correct key on Mac:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
```