# How do I update nodemailer to use https (SSL)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, https, nodemailer

I'm setting up an angular website and the final thing I need to do to get it working is fix the contact form. I had it working on an insecure version of the site but since forcing users to the https version via a URL rewrite rule I am no longer able to send emails.

The error I got was is "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.MyWebsite.com/home#contact-us' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.MyWebsite.com:3000/send'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

I changed the endpoint to https ('https://www.MyWebsite.com:3000/send') and now I get a different error: "OPTIONS https://www.MyWebsite.com:3000/send net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".
I'm not sure where the fault lies but I'm thinking I need to change something in the server.js running on the backend.

NodeMailer Service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class NodeMailerService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    sendEmail(name, email, phone, message) {
        const url = "https://www.MyWebsite.com:3000/send";

        const obj = {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            message: message
        };

        return this.http.post(url, obj, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }),
            responseType: "text"
        });
    }
}
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const hostServer = "mail.MyWebsite.com";
const receiverAddress = ["website@MyWebsite.com"]; // Enter the email address to send the emails TO
const userAccount = "website@MyWebsite.com"; // Enter the email address to send the emails FROM
const userPass = "Password1" // Enter the password for the above user account

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: hostServer,
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: userAccount,
        pass: userPass
    },
    tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3',
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
});

app.post("/send", function(req, res) {
    let senderName = req.body.name;
    let senderEmail = req.body.email;
    let senderPhone = req.body.phone;
    let messageSubject = "Website - Contact Request";

    let messageText = "Name: " + senderName + "\n";
    messageText += "Email: " + senderEmail + "\n";
    messageText += "Phone: " + senderPhone + "\n";
    messageText += "Message: " + req.body.message + "\n";

    let mailOptions = {
        to: receiverAddress,
        from: senderEmail,
        subject: messageSubject,
        text: messageText,
        replyTo: senderEmail
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.end("error");
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent: ", response);
            res.end("sent");
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Express started on port: ", port);
});
```

I updated it to use secure: true but I still get the same error message as before.

Am I missing something or am I even looking in the right place?
I'm new enough to this kind of full stack web development so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Can it help ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892547/nodejs-https-server-returning-err-ssl-protocol-error-using-express

Comment: From looking at that link I might be taking the wrong approach to this. So it's not that I need to update the nodemailer code but I need to serve the server.js app itself over a https connection which requires me to create cert and key files?
I have an SSL cert for the website already that works perfectly for the website itself(Using 'Certify The Web'. Is there a way to tie that cert in with the node app or are the two to be treated separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was looking at the wrong piece of code for this.
The problem wasn't with nodemailer but with how I was serving the node app on the server. I've updated my server.js file in line with what was in the post that @candybeer pointed me towards. [NodeJS https server returning ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR using express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892547/nodejs-https-server-returning-err-ssl-protocol-error-using-express)

From windows certificate manager I was able to export the cert to a pfx file, convert that to .PEM files using an online tool and then put them in the server.js folder and used them with https to listen on the port.

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require("fs");

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
}

// app.listen(port, function() {
//     console.log("Express started on port: ", port);
// });

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Express started on port: ", port);
});
```

Thanks @candybeer. Much appreciated